# How to extract multiple files at the same time in ubuntu terminal using unrar command?

Tags: ubuntu, unrar

I have about 100 rar files in a directory and I want to extract them in the same directory using unrar in the terminal in Ubuntu 20.04.
I use the following command to unrar them one by one and it's OK:

```
unrar e -pMy_Password RandomFileName.rar
```

How can I extract all the files at the same time?

filenames don't have a specific pattern but all of the are rar files.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful with the following command(without creating a bash file):

```
for f in *.rar; do unrar e -pMyPassword $f done;
```

after that, it would want input, and I entered done and it began to extract the files successfully.
Unfortunately, I don't know why it needed another "done", however, it worked well.

in the command, "e" parameter stands for "extract" and you have to input your password immediately after the -p switch.

Answer (score 1):

Close.

```
for f in *.rar; do unrar e -pMyPassword "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
unrar -P PASSWORD  '*.rar'
```